# Can you use two verbs in simple past tense in a row like this?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure, word-order, past-simple

Is the usage of the verbs "measured & compared" correct in the following sentence?

> We will assess network performance in this regard **measured compared** to the protocol which hops over other nodes

Comment: Stylistically it's a bit clumsy to include ***measured*** - which adds nothing to the intended meaning, since you obviously couldn't ***compare*** performances unless you somehow "quantified, measured" them. Note that it's almost impossible to make a syntactic case for the two words ***measured compared*** occurring consecutively without intervening ***and*** like that (it's certainly not valid in your *exact* context). Presumably the bit about ***in this regard*** refers back to some specific *aspect* of measurable performance introduced in preceding text.

Comment: (Credible example: *We graphed the speed measured compared to the speed claimed in the documentation*.)

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical with those two verbs; moreover, I have no clear idea what you are hoping to say. How can you compare performance to a protocol?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Presumably, the comparison is to the *(measured?) network performance (in this regard?)*, ***of some other system, which is configured to use*** the "node-hopping" protocol. Whatever that means.

Comment: "in this regard measured" =?  "so measured"

Comment: Although it does not make much difference to the thrust of the question, the OP is really asking about stringing **participles** together. In this case, the stringing is both ungrammatical and redundant, and either participle on its own is OK. Even then, the prose makes me cringe. Maybe **In this regard, we shall assess performance by measuring it against that of the protocol that hops over other nodes.**

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this, using **compare** as the main verb?

We will compare the performance of the network in this respect to that of a network which uses the "node-hopping" protocol.

... or whatever you'd like to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using "*assess*", which here means the same thing as "*measured*". Using just "*compared*" would read better than "*measured compared*".

That gives:
"*We will assess network performance in this regard compared to the protocol which hops over other nodes*"

It is also odd to use "*in this regard*" for the current design\protocol and compare to another "*protocol*". So I would recommend using:
"*We will assess network performance for this protocol compared to the protocol which hops over other nodes*"

Answer (score -2):

> We will assess network performance in this regard measured compared to the protocol which hops over other nodes

It doesn't scan as written, as a general rule (there's always exceptions!) if using two verbs together the second verb should take the infinitive form so the above would become:

> We will assess network performance in this regard measured **to compare** to the protocol which hops over other nodes

but that doesn't really work either, it's legal grammar but doesn't scan particularly well.

> We will assess network performance in this regard **compared** to the protocol which hops over other nodes

"compared" *implies* some form of measurement taking place in process of comparing. If you wanted to be referring to pre-existing measurements being used you would use:

> We will assess measured network performance in this regard measured compared to the protocol which hops over other nodes

It gets you around the infinitive issue.

Comment: I don't find your first *(...measured to compare...)* alternative remotely acceptable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you know what, reading it back I really have to agree with you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Might I suggest that what OP means is "assess performance ... measured in comparison to ...". That's not a felicitous way of putting it, either--*assess* and *measure* are really redundant. I'd say "measure .. in comparison to"

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed. However we attempt to parse things, it seems we're dealing with inherently clunky phrasing. Within which context we've also got to keep track of whatever ***in this regard*** refers back to. Maybe it would be better for OP to just forget about trying to include so many different referents and relationships in a single sentence. Perhaps the way forward is something along the lines of *Write whatever you're trying to say as a long series of **very short** sentences, **then** see if you can **usefully** collapse any of it into more complex sentences.*